# I am not getting jsonArray in java?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to get the json data from properties file in java.

emailServer.properties

```
{ 
   "Servers":
   [ 
      { 
         "Name":"Server1",
         "UserName":"abcde@yahoo.in",
         "Password":"something",
         "Port":"993",
         "FolderName":"Server1"
      },
      { 
         "Name":"Server2",
         "UserName":"fghijk@gmail.co",
         "Password":"something",
         "Port":"993",
         "FolderName":"Server2"
      }
   ]
}
```

When i am trying to get servers array it is showing  The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject. How to solve this?
Here is my java code :-

```
public void configure()
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try
        {
            String propertyFileName = "emailServer.properties";
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "StandardCharsets.UTF_8"));
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            JSONArray jadata = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Servers");
            System.out.println(jadata);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: `server.properties` != `emailServer.properties`

Comment: Sorry man, I mispelled the properties file.

Comment: which json parser are you using?

Comment: Are you importing the right JSONObject class?

Comment: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Comment: What are the outputs of System.out?

Comment: I'd like to suggest not to call the file ".properties". Java properties are a specific format that you are not using. Using the wrong extension may confuse users and software. Better call it ".json".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using
`jsonObject.getJSONArray("Servers")`, 
you can use

`JSONArray jadata =(JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Servers")`

which may can solve your problem or if you still getting the issues then you can use google json library like Gson which you can find on maven and use below line:

```
yourjsonPojo[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, yourjsonPojo[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks man, Now i am getting. But there comes another issue, i am not getting the server1 and server2 details.                                                                                       
                        int len = jadata.size();
   for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
    JSONArray jobject = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("UserName");
    System.out.println(jobject);
   }

Comment: Now again, your json array contain json objects so, you need to iterate over it to get Server1 and Server2 like this for (int i = 0; i <jadata.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject obj= jsonArray.get(i);
   String videoId=obj.get("server1");
       
}

Comment: Im getting exception like java.util.ArrayList can't cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray.. Please could you help me? why I'm getting this error.